# Call to undefined function recaptcha_get_html() How to fix?

Tags: php

Hello all im getting the following error. I tried putting the files everywhere i can and no fix. is there something else i have to do to make this work? thanks here is the error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function recaptcha_get_html() in /home/folder/public_html/site/views/users/register.php on line 75
```

Comment: Does this have anything to do with Perl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function **`recaptcha_get_html()`** has to be *visible* from the file you're trying to use it : to be able to call that function, PHP must know it.

Here, you are using this function in `register.php`.

But that function is *(I guess)* defined in another file.

Which means you have to *include* or require that other file, from `register.php` *(or another file that's required by it)*.

See the [**`require`**](https://www.php.net/require) and [**`include`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php), and their *_once* versions : [**`require_once`**](https://www.php.net/require_once) and [**`include_once`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php).

For example, at the beginning of `register.php`, you could have something like this :

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../libraries/recaptcha.php';
```

Of course, up to you to adapt the path to the file ;-)